# Python code doesn't work after imported from PyCharm to Repl.it (ParseError: bad input)

Tags: python, pycharm, parse-error, replit

I was working on a simple one-point perspective 3D-Engine in PyCharm which uses Turtle to render images. The code simply just renders three (badly-made) stars floating around and changing colours. I've also worked on the site repl.it tons of hours before, and thought that I would "upload" my code there so that I could continue working on it online from other places when I got time. But it seems as if there were a difference between the two compilers in PyCharm and Repl.it: The exact same code that works fine in PyCharm just spits out a Compiler Error in Repl.it. The exact error is `ParseError: bad input on line 59` which is really annoying. Here below is the code. I don't expect anyone to read all the code, but rather just take a quick look at that specific line to see if it's just me being a moron. *Just a heads up, it's very long!*

```
    import turtle
    import time
    import math

    turtle.getscreen()
    turtle.colormode(255)
    turtle.bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
    turtle.pensize(7)
    turtle.speed(99)


    def draw_line(start_x, start_y, start_z, end_x, end_y, end_z, shift_x, shift_y, shift_z):
        fov = 10
        turtle.penup()
        print("Drawing Line -- First pos: " + str(fov*((start_x+shift_x)/(start_z+shift_z))) + ", Second pos: " + str(fov*((start_y+shift_y)/(start_z+shift_z))))
        turtle.goto(fov*((start_x+shift_x)/(start_z+shift_z)), fov*((start_y+shift_y)/(start_z+shift_z)))
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(fov*((end_x+shift_x)/(end_z+shift_z)), fov*((end_y+shift_y)/(end_z+shift_z)))
        turtle.penup()


    def draw_star(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z):
        turtle.tracer(0, 0)

        draw_line(-10, -10, 1,  0, 10, 1,  pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(0, 10, 1,  10, -10, 1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, -10, 1,  -10, 3, 1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(-10, 3, 1,  10, 3, 1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, 3, 1, -10, -10, 1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)

        draw_line(-10, -10, 1.1,  0, 10, 1.1,  pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(0, 10, 1.1,  10, -10, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, -10, 1.1,  -10, 3, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(-10, 3, 1.1,  10, 3, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, 3, 1.1, -10, -10, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)

        draw_line(-10, -10, 1, -10, -10, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(0, 10, 1,  0, 10, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, -10, 1,  10, -10, 1.1,  pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(-10, 3, 1, -10, 3, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        draw_line(10, 3, 1,  10, 3, 1.1, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z)
        print("Finished drawing star at " + str(pos_x) + " " + str(pos_y) + " " + str(pos_z))

        turtle.update()


    i = 0
    i2 = 0
    i3 = 0
    clr = 0
    back = False

    while True:
        turtle.clear()

        valuelist = [math.cos(i/1.2), math.cos(i2/1.2), math.cos(i3/1.2)]
        sortedlist = sorted(valuelist)

        match (sortedlist.index(valuelist[len(valuelist) - 3])):
            case 0:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255-clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5-(math.cos(i/1.2)*3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i)*10-30, math.sin(i)*10, math.cos(i/1.2)/3)
            case 1:
                turtle.pencolor(255-clr, clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i2 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i2)*10, math.sin(i2)*10, math.cos(i2/1.2)/3)
            case 2:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255-clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i3 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i3)*10+30, math.sin(i3)*10, math.cos(i3/1.2)/3)

        match (sortedlist.index(valuelist[len(valuelist) - 2])):
            case 0:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255 - clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i) * 10 - 30, math.sin(i) * 10, math.cos(i / 1.2) / 3)
            case 1:
                turtle.pencolor(255 - clr, clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i2 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i2) * 10, math.sin(i2) * 10, math.cos(i2 / 1.2) / 3)
            case 2:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255 - clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i3 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i3) * 10 + 30, math.sin(i3) * 10, math.cos(i3 / 1.2) / 3)

        match (sortedlist.index(valuelist[len(valuelist) - 1])):
            case 0:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255 - clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i) * 10 - 30, math.sin(i) * 10, math.cos(i / 1.2) / 3)
            case 1:
                turtle.pencolor(255 - clr, clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i2 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i2) * 10, math.sin(i2) * 10, math.cos(i2 / 1.2) / 3)
            case 2:
                turtle.pencolor(clr, 255 - clr, clr)
                turtle.pensize(5 - (math.cos(i3 / 1.2) * 3))
                draw_star(math.cos(i3) * 10 + 30, math.sin(i3) * 10, math.cos(i3 / 1.2) / 3)

        i = i + 0.2
        i2 = i2 - 0.25
        i3 = i3 + 0.3

        if clr > 245:
            back = True

        if clr < 15:
            back = False

        if back:
            clr = clr - 15
        else:
            clr = clr + 15

        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `match` syntax is new with python version 3.10.  If the interpreter you're submitting this to is an earlier version you'll get a SyntaxError on line 59.

Note that version 3.10 just came out 2 months ago.  This is still bleeding-edge syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to check it out tomorrow. Do you think you could add an alternative to using ```match```?